# Docker Toolbox - Shows the same website

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am new to Docker and I want to start an Apache Server with Docker.
But it shows the same Website, even if I delete the whole directory and creating a new one ...

My Dockerfile:

```
 FROM httpd:2.4
 COPY ./HTML/ ./htdocs/
 //in HTML/ are my html files ^^
```

In HTML/ is my ad.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>KRASS!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       LDLALDLADAPjF<br/>djafijafija</br>auohf<br/>dddad
   </body>
</html>
```

And in docker I am doing it like it is shown here https://store.docker.com/images/httpd , but I am adding the -p

```
$ docker build -t my-apache2 .
$ docker run -dit -p 4000:80 --name my-running-app my-apache2
```

And like I said above, then I enter the page via my ID:4000, it just shows "It works!" which was the content of my first try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link](https://store.docker.com/images/httpd) you provided, it seems that the `html` files should be copied inside: `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/` and not: `./htdocs`

> ### How to use this image.
>
> If you want to run a simple HTML server, add a simple Dockerfile to your project where `public-html/` is the directory containing all your HTML.
>
> #### Create a `Dockerfile` in your project
>
> ```
> FROM httpd:2.4
> COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
> ```

Comment: Yeah, this was my first try -> Havent worked ... So my idea was to use another directory

Comment: I have put a file named `index.html` inside my `public-html` folder, it was successfully copied in the docker image after `docker build` and I was able to access it at `http://172.17.0.2/index.html`.

Comment: Since you are using `ad.html`, try to access it at `[your_container's_ip]:4000/ad.html`

Comment: Love You <3 ;) That was my fault ^^

Comment: By the way do I need to create the directory where the files shall be copied to?